# Basic data validation in AWS Glue against schema/expected file format, including row level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-workflow

I am new to AWS. Need to process the daily feeds (should be same format every day) received via SFTP and loaded into S3, then processed by AWS Glue and loaded into the database. I.e.:

**SFTP --> Amazon S3 --> AWS Glue --> Validate data --> Load into Aurora DB**

How can I validate the data received from S3 against a certain pre-defined schema?
How do I log/report/send alerts for when some elements in the file are not valid?
Does it allow the row level validation (i.e., row 5 and 9 invalid, but the rest of the file can be valid)?

I searched online and cannot find this basic information.

Comment: If the data coming in S3 is not so big then you can consider to write a python script and run that through airflow? or make use of Step Functions I guess.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. Yes, the data is not big, but the question is extendability/flexibility. So if today I have 1 feed, tomorrow I may have 100 feeds. What about this schema validation? I see it mentioned in a few places. Would be great if I could validate against some kind of schema.

Comment: So, in terms of schema I if you want to do true AWS way Glue Databrew. I have never used it and just looked up that it is possible. But in the simplistic case, I would define the database and the schemas for the tables. If so I will receive an exception and I can handle that or clean right. In the similar fashion, pandas could also be helpful?

Comment: DataBrew is not yet approved in our company and is not likely to be approved for a while. I am just surprised there is not default/basic data validation mechanism in AWS Glue.

Comment: Have you tried with AWS Glue Studio? That should be easy to start with. In Glue Studio, you can do many things using Transform option. For example, drop null fields, do custom transform etc. However, for alerts, you might need to write a custom script (within AWS Glue) and invoke Lambda or SNS for alerts using boto3 python library or call any other API using requests.

Comment: To Myz: yes, thanks so much. I did look into the AWS Glue Studio. I understand the transformation rules. But even forgetting the alerts. Say your feed (same format every day) comes on Tuesday with missing account number in row #20 - I would like to be able to reject this row and log the rejection. Ideally, would like to have schema validation. Schema defines data types, field length, non-null fields and validates the daily file for those rules. Is there something like this in AWS Glue?

Comment: Probably not out of the box in AWS Glue but I see possibilities with writing your own custom job script in AWS Glue including alert functionality.

Comment: Another question: let's assume we write this custom job script in AWS Glue. How do we control the versions of this script? In other words, assume we maintain the scripts in a GIT repository. If we make a change to this script, do we deploy to AWS Glue manually or is there automated way to update the script (if you know)?

Comment: I don't think AWS Glue has any version control (at least not that I am aware of). AWS Glue stores all the scripts in S3 bucket. So, one option is to enable versioning for this bucket so that whenever you upload new version, S3 will keep a copy of the old version. IMO, this is not a very good option for version control. Instead we have repo with webhook which connects to a Lambda function. Upon merge, webhook is triggered and the lambda copies the code from repo to s3 bucket. This solution is very specific to our use-case and might be different for you.